# Jboss Erro 09:51:36,559 INFO** [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel)

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jboss

Estou tentando executar aplicação utilizando o Jboss 4.2, mas quando tento inicia-lo, tenho a seguinte informação no console e não sai disso.

```
10:42:39,847 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
10:42:39,848 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)
10:42:39,850 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: C:\SofttekProjects\Sun\jboss-4.2.2.GA
10:42:39,850 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/C:/SofttekProjects/Sun/jboss-4.2.2.GA/
10:42:39,851 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
10:42:39,851 INFO  [Server] Server Name: default
10:42:39,851 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: C:\SofttekProjects\Sun\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default
10:42:39,851 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/C:/SofttekProjects/Sun/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/
10:42:39,851 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: C:\SofttekProjects\Sun\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\log
10:42:39,852 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: C:\SofttekProjects\Sun\jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\tmp
10:42:39,852 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
10:42:40,147 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.5.0_22,Sun Microsystems Inc.
10:42:40,148 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.5.0_22-b03,Sun Microsystems Inc.
10:42:40,148 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
10:42:40,540 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
10:42:42,581 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://localhost:8083/
10:42:42,583 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
10:42:42,867 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
10:42:42,867 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
10:42:42,986 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting recovery manager
10:42:43,161 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager started
10:42:43,161 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
10:42:45,136 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Starting java:comp multiplexer
10:42:45,440 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for null
10:42:45,443 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for null
10:42:45,464 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for null
10:42:45,485 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for {urn:jboss:bean-deployer}supplyType
10:42:45,496 INFO  [STDOUT] no object for {urn:jboss:bean-deployer}dependsType
10:42:47,556 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Native
10:42:47,556 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] jbossws-native-2.0.1.SP2 (build=200710210837)
10:42:48,414 INFO  [Embedded] Catalina naming disabled
10:42:48,564 INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_22\bin;.;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;native;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\oracle\ora81\bin;C:\Progra Files (x86)\Oracle\jre\1.1.7\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Adaptive Server Anywhere 6.0\win32;C:\Program Files\Sybase\Adaptive Server Anywhere 6.0\win32;C:\Program Files\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin
10:42:48,641 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
10:42:48,648 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
10:42:48,648 INFO  [Catalina] Initialization processed in 233 ms
10:42:48,648 INFO  [StandardService] Starting service jboss.web
10:42:48,650 INFO  [StandardEngine] Starting Servlet Engine: JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA
10:42:48,699 INFO  [Catalina] Server startup in 50 ms
10:42:48,788 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/, warUrl=.../deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/
10:42:49,262 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker, warUrl=.../deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/
10:42:49,407 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws, warUrl=.../deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war/
10:42:49,501 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossmq-httpil, warUrl=.../deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/
10:42:50,037 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console, warUrl=.../deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/
10:42:50,363 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
10:42:50,562 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-local-jdbc.rar
10:42:50,611 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-xa-jdbc.rar
10:42:50,653 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar
10:42:50,696 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar
10:42:50,760 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jms/jms-ra.rar
10:42:50,802 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/mail-ra.rar
10:42:50,854 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/quartz-ra.rar
10:42:50,866 INFO  [QuartzResourceAdapter] start quartz!!!
10:42:50,927 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
10:42:50,950 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
10:42:50,953 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
10:42:50,953 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
10:42:50,953 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
10:42:50,953 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
10:42:51,816 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
10:42:52,031 INFO  [A] Bound to JNDI name: queue/A
10:42:52,033 INFO  [B] Bound to JNDI name: queue/B
10:42:52,034 INFO  [C] Bound to JNDI name: queue/C
10:42:52,035 INFO  [D] Bound to JNDI name: queue/D
10:42:52,037 INFO  [ex] Bound to JNDI name: queue/ex
10:42:52,052 INFO  [testTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testTopic
10:42:52,054 INFO  [securedTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/securedTopic
10:42:52,055 INFO  [testDurableTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testDurableTopic
10:42:52,057 INFO  [testQueue] Bound to JNDI name: queue/testQueue
10:42:52,090 INFO  [UILServerILService] JBossMQ UIL service available at : localhost/127.0.0.1:8093
10:42:52,116 INFO  [DLQ] Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ
10:42:52,214 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
10:42:52,296 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=geDS' to JNDI name 'java:geDS'
10:42:52,302 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=geSphDS' to JNDI name 'java:geSphDS'
10:42:52,352 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=gePopulisDS' to JNDI name 'java:gePopulisDS'
10:42:52,384 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console, warUrl=.../deploy/jmx-console.war/
10:42:52,564 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
10:42:52,578 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
10:42:52,587 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)] Started in 12s:732ms
```

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo fazer com que a aplicação execute normalmente.

Comment: No arquivo de log não aparece nenhum erro ou warning que possa ser referente a sua aplicação?

Comment: Bom dia Adelmo,
No Console só vejo INFOS, nenhum Warning ou Erro.

Comment: Quer que mando tudo que recebo de INFO no console?

Comment: Sim. Assim fica melhor para te ajudar

Comment: Adelmo, atualizei o corpo da pergunta com tudo que tenho no console do Eclipse. Da pra entender dessa maneira?

Comment: Não encontrei no log a informação de que a sua aplicação está sendo inicializada. O arquivo .war está na pasta correta?

Comment: Entendo que la no final está mostrando e também na Aba Servers, está mostrando que o Jboss está startado.
Verifiquei que localhost funcionou normalmente quando coloquei no IE apenas http://localhost:8080

O arquivo war está no meu workspace.